# Unable to bypass error in order to change user input to integer

Tags: python

```
day_left = input("What day are you leaving?")

Sunday = int(0)
Monday = int(1)
Tuesday = int(2)
Wednesday = int(3)
Thursday = int(4)
Friday = int(5)
Saturday = int(6)


days_gone = int(input("How many days are you going to be gone?"))



day_return = day_left + days_gone

day_week = day_return % 7

print(day_week)
```

Please excuse me if there is a very simple way to do this as I am just beginning to jump into the world of programming, starting with Python 3.4(as in first time ever). I was able to complete the basic function by having the user input a integer(ie; 0-6 for Sunday through Saturday, 3 for Wednesday, etc) for the day of the week that they were leaving.

Trying to make it more functional I seem to be running into this error:

```
line 18, in <module>
    day_return = day_left + days_gone
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.Thanks for any help you can provide.

Also if I did anything wrong in my first post on here, please feel free to point it out; as I've been told this is an excellent source to get answers and hope to continue to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`days_left` is a string, but you converted `days_gone` to an integer. You cannot sum the two.

You probably wanted to convert `days_left` too:

```
day_left = int(input("What day are you leaving?"))
```

Next, I see you created variables for each day of the week; you don't need to use `int()` when using literals, the `0`, `1`, etc. already produce `int` values:

```
Sunday = 0
Monday = 1
Tuesday = 2
Wednesday = 3
Thursday = 4
Friday = 5
Saturday = 6
```

You cannot (easily) map an integer back to those names, however. You probably just want to create a *sequence* here:

```
weekdays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
```

You can then *index* into this list to get a string for each day of the week as represented by an integer:

```
>>> weekdays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
>>> weekdays[3]
'Wednesday'
```

Comment: @Khalixo: ... allowing you to use `print(weekdays[day_week])`.

Answer (score 0):

First line should cast to integer like so:

```
day_left = int(input("What day are you leaving?"))
```

Basically, your current code is trying to add a string to an integer. What is the result of `'something' + 3`? It simply can't be done

Answer (score 0):

`day_left` is a string so `day_return` is attempting to combine an integer and a string.

If you're just starting out with programming using an if/elif statement is one easy way to change the string input to an integer, `day_left_integer`.

```
day_left = input("What day are you leaving?")

if day_left == "Sunday":
    day_left_integer = 0
elif day_left == "Monday":
    day_left_integer = 1
elif day_left == "Tuesday":
    day_left_integer = 2
elif day_left == "Wednesday":
    day_left_integer = 3
elif day_left == "Thursday":
    day_left_integer = 4
elif day_left == "Friday":
    day_left_integer = 5
elif day_left == "Saturday":
    day_left_integer = 6


days_gone = int(input("How many days are you going to be gone?"))


day_return = day_left_integer + days_gone

day_week = day_return % 7

print(day_week)
```